# pairs() move labels to sides of scatter plot

Tags: r

For the iris data, we get the scatter plot using the pairs() function as below:

```
pairs(iris[1:4], 
      main = "Edgar Anderson's Iris Data", 
      lower.panel=panel.pearson, 
      pch = 21, 
      bg = c("red", "green3", "blue")[unclass(iris$Species)])
```

With the function panel.pearson defined as follows:

`panel.pearson <- function(x, y, ...) {
           horizontal <- (par("usr")[1] + par("usr")[2]) / 2;
           vertical <- (par("usr")[3] + par("usr")[4]) / 2;
           text(horizontal, vertical, format(abs(cor(x,y)), digits=2)) }`

I needed to convert the lower panel to correlation matrix and remove the labels from the diagonal and put them along the right and bottom axes. I tried the following:

```
pairs(iris[1:4], 
      main = "Edgar Anderson's Iris Data", 
      labels=NULL, 
      lower.panel=panel.pearson, 
      xaxt='n', 
      yaxt='n', 
      pch = 21, 
      bg = c("red", "green3", "blue")[unclass(iris$Species)])
```

This gives me what I need. Except that I do not understand how to get the labels on the bottom and right axes (the variable labels, I mean, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width etc..). Any help is tremendously appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible code? My R doesn't know `panel.pearson`.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. I missed the function and have added it along. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
# Horizontal axis
text(seq(.2, 2, length.out=4), 0,
     c("Sepal Length","Sepal Width","Petal Length","Petal Width"),
     xpd=TRUE, adj=c(0,.5), cex=.9)

# Vertical axis
text(0, seq(0.35, 2.05, length.out=4),
     rev(c("Sepal Length","Sepal Width","Petal Length","Petal Width")),
     xpd=TRUE, adj=c(0.5, 0), 
     srt=90,  # rotates text to be parallel to axis
     cex=.9)
```

I positioned the labels by trial and error. There's probably a better way, but at least this gets the labels in (nearly) the right place.

**Update**: A [new SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652161/how-can-i-use-a-jpg-or-other-format-image-as-a-background-in-a-histogram-using) gave me an idea for a slightly better way to position the axis labels. As the linked answer points out, you can get the current coordinates of the plot area with `par('usr')`. So here's an update to the code, based on that:

```
x.coords = par('usr')[1:2]
y.coords = par('usr')[3:4]

# Offset is estimated distance between edge of plot area and beginning of actual plot
x.offset = 0.03 * (x.coords[2] - x.coords[1])  
xrng =  (x.coords[2] - x.coords[1]) - 2*x.offset
x.width = xrng/4  

y.offset = 0.028 * (y.coords[2] - y.coords[1])
yrng =  (y.coords[2] - y.coords[1]) - 2*y.offset
y.width = yrng/4  

# seq function below calculates the location of the midpoint of each panel

# x-axis labels
text(seq(x.coords[1] + x.offset + 0.5*x.width, x.coords[2] - x.offset - 0.5*x.width,
         length.out=4), 0,
     c("Sepal Length","Sepal Width","Petal Length","Petal Width"),
     xpd=TRUE,adj=c(.5,.5), cex=.9)

# y-axis labels
text(0, seq(y.coords[1] + y.offset + 0.5*y.width, y.coords[2] - 3*y.offset - 0.5*y.width, 
     length.out=4),
     rev(c("Sepal Length","Sepal Width","Petal Length","Petal Width")),
     xpd=TRUE, adj=c(0.5, 0.5), 
     srt=90,  # rotates text to be parallel to axis
     cex=.9)
```

It's still not ideal, because the size of the offset is determined by trial and error. If someone knows how R determines the size of the offset between the boundary of the plot area and where the actual plot begins, then the offset can be determined programmatically also.

Comment: Thanks eipi10. However, I was thinking on the lines of a more automated way. Perhaps, have an x-axis with discrete labels and a y-axis on the right with the same. I want to be able to do this repeatedly too.

Comment: If you can figure out how the `pairs` function lays out the coordinates for the plot area, you may be able to adapt my code above into a function that will add labels centered under each column and beside each row of plots.

Comment: Yes, that's just what I need. Thanks eipi10! But any suggestions how do I find out how the pairs function lays out the coordinates for the plot area?

Comment: @Nerdstat I've updated my answer with a (hopefully) improved answer to your question.