# How can i use a jpg (or other format) image as a background in a histogram using R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overlay data onto Background image in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993189/overlay-data-onto-background-image-in-r)

I have seen nice graphics with a photo in the background. So it is possible?

May I ask the experts how to place a photo, JPG, or if necessary other format, in the background of a classical histogram so that the borders touch the X and Y axes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rasterImage` function to add a raster to an existing graph, it will then be the background for anything added on top of that.  See the link in @mplourde's comment  for ways to read jpeg or other image formats in that can then be used with `rasterImage`.

Running `par('usr')` will give you the current user coordinates to plot from axis to axis or you can use `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` to find other sets of coordinates.  So for a histogram you could plot the histogram, then use `rasterImage` to place your image, then use hist again with `add=TRUE`:

```
tmp <- rnorm(100)
hist(tmp)
image <- as.raster(matrix(0:1, ncol=5, nrow=3))
tmp2 <- par('usr')
rasterImage(image, tmp2[1], tmp2[3], tmp2[2], tmp2[4])
hist(tmp, add=TRUE, border='red', lwd=3)
```

However, be very careful that the background image does not distract from the histogram itself, possibly fading your image or adding an alpha channel to make it semitransparent can help.

Comment: That is nice Greg. Should i replace matrix () with myimage.jpg in line 3. Thanks i 'll see also the link in @mplourde's comment to get things working.

Comment: You need to import the file, not just give the filename.  the link mentioned shows ways to import the files.

Comment: It works and it looks great. I did not change color or transparency. My photos in green fluorescence and black background, I gave the bars a green color with blue borders. I may just give a darker margin outside the plotting area and draw a black border all around the image.