# How to auto adjust R figure axis labels to matrix size?

Tags: r, resize, axis-labels

I want to make the fontsize of the y-axis labels adjustable to the input data size on the y-axis like in Fig. 3, in contrast to the current situation in Fig. 1-2 where labels are not next to the corresponding lines. 
Code

```
library("corrgram")

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/40387233/54964
ids <- seq(1,18)
x_at <- seq(0.075, 0.925, length.out = length(ids))
y_at <- seq(0.075, 0.91, length.out = length(ids))

createLabels <- function(xlab, ylab, x_labels, y_labels){
ids <- y_labels # assume here
x_at <- seq(0.075, 0.925, length.out = length(ids))
y_at <- seq(0.075, 0.91, length.out = length(ids))
mtext(xlab, side = 1, line = 4)
mtext(ylab, side = 2, line = 3)
axis(1, at=x_at, labels=x_labels, line = 1.5, tick=F, cex.axis=.7)
axis(2, at=y_at, labels=y_labels, line = 1, tick=F, cex.axis=.7, las=1) # horizontal y-axis labels; rawr
}

corrgram(baseball,main="Baseball data PC2/PC1 order")
createLabels(xlab="Patient 1 ID", ylab="Patient 2 ID", x_labels=ids, y_labels=ids)
```

Fig. 1 Output with the limited test data *baseball*, 
Fig. 2 Output with the real case, 
Fig. 3 Expected output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Expected output: automatically adjustable label font size to the input data size on the y-axis; example of the output created by `makeMatrixPlot(list, ids, title)` found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23429739/) in Fig. 3

### Testing Istrel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40485734/54964) with big data set where long IDs

Complete code [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23462038/) which visualises correctly but gives backside strange outputs an `NULL`s, here some key points about optimised parameters

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/40485734/54964
cex_lab<-0.9 # little smaller fontsize for matrix >= 20x20
oma<-c(4, 4, 6, 4)
gap<-0
las<-2 # both axis labels always perpendicular
```

Output complications as the warning and many NULLs

> ```
> In max(l.wid) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> ```

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL
...
[[1]][[7]]
NULL


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL
...    
[[2]][[7]]
NULL


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
NULL
...  
[[3]][[7]]
NULL
```

Call it for instance by

```
library("corrplot")
library("psych")

ids <- seq(1,11) 

M.cor <- cor(mtcars)
colnames(M.cor) <- ids
rownames(M.cor) <- ids

p.mat <- psych::corr.test(M.cor, adjust = "none", ci = F)
p.mat <- p.mat[["r"]]

corrplot(M.cor, 
  method = "color", 
  type = "upper", 
  tl.col = 'black', 
  diag = TRUE, 
  p.mat = p.mat, 
  sig.level = 0.0000005
)

createLabels(xlab="Patient 1 ID", ylab="Patient 2 ID and Ages", x_labels=ids, y_labels="")
```

R: 3.3.1
Used graphic objects: `corrplot`, `corrgram`, ...
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `corrgram` package has been updated (version 1.11) with better support for labels along the axes.  I've used the basic idea from Leo and added it to the package.  For example:

```
require(corrgram)
labs=colnames(state.x77)
corrgram(state.x77, oma=c(7, 7, 2, 2),
         outer.labels=list(bottom=list(labels=labs,cex=1.5,srt=60),
                           left=list(labels=labs,cex=1.5,srt=30)))
mtext("Bottom", side=1, cex=2, line = -1.5, outer=TRUE, xpd=NA)
mtext("Left", side=2, cex=2, line = -1.5, outer=TRUE, xpd=NA)
```

[image: corrgram]

Comment: Confirmed, the support for labels is better supported in `corrgram` 1.11 now. Thank you for the news and update!

Answer (score 2):

Corrgram uses `mfrow` from `par()` for squares drawing. We can use that for labeling. The number of labels should be equal to the number of columns in the matrix. If you set `oma` or `gap` arguments in `corrgram` function, you have to specify same parameters in `createLabels` function.

BTW, if you use `corrgram` without `main` argument, you will need `oma=c(4,4,4,4)` in `createLabels`

```
createLabels <- function(xlab, ylab, x_labels, y_labels, 
                cex_lab=1.3, oma=c(4, 4, 6, 4), gap=0, las=0){
# oma and gap args same as in corrgram
nc <- length(x_labels) # get number of columns

# Inititate mfrow partition as in corrgram
opar <- par(mfrow = c(nc, nc), mar = rep.int(gap/2, 4), oma = oma) #save old par parameters

# Create matrix of outer cells indexes and positions
left_side <- matrix(c(nc:1, rep(1, nc), rep(2, nc)), nc)
bottom_side <- matrix(c(rep(nc, nc), 1:nc, rep(1, nc)), nc)
sides <- rbind(left_side, bottom_side)


# Dublicate labels vector
labels <- c(y_labels, x_labels)

# Loop over each outer cell
for (i in c(1:(nc*2))){
    cell_ind <- sides[i, ]
    par(mfg=c(cell_ind[1], cell_ind[2], nc, nc)) # set current plotting cell
    usr<-par("usr")
    clip(usr[1], -2, usr[3], usr[4]) # alter clipping region
    axis(cell_ind[3], at=0.5, labels=labels[i], 
        outer=TRUE, xpd=NA, lwd=NA, mgp=c(3,0,0.2), cex.axis=cex_lab, las=las)
}

# Add labels
par(opar)
mtext(xlab, side = 1, line = -1.5, outer=TRUE, xpd=NA)
mtext(ylab, side = 2, line = -1.5, outer=TRUE, xpd=NA)
}

corrgram(baseball,main="Baseball data PC2/PC1 order")
createLabels(xlab="Patient 1 ID", ylab="Patient 2 ID", 1:18, 1:18)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `1:18` is an argument of a function. i.e. `createLabels("X-lab", "Y-lab", x_labels=c(1:18))`. So you can specify any vector of names, while its length is equal to data size. What if you will need names like c("a", "b", "c")

Comment: I have added y_labels. Try it now. Of course, you can move those arguments as hard-coded variables.

Comment: Try `las=2`, i.e. always perpendicular. As for font size, it is `cex_lab` argument, try to change it.

Comment: Initially, you asked about `corrgram`. Now you say that you have a problem with `corrplot`.

Comment: Also, for my function you need labels vectors of length exactly equal to data dimensions. I.e. for your example `x_labels` AND `y_labels` should be of length 11 (in your snippet, the length of `y_labels` is equal to 1).

Comment: And what that `ages` variable is?

Comment: Try `y_labels=rep("", 11)` to make a vector of 11 `""`.